# How to solve this differential equation in Python?

Tags: python, math, scipy, ode, differential-equations

```
y''' + yy" + (1 - y'^2)= 0 y(0)=0, y'(0)=0, y'(+∞)=1
```

*(The `+∞` can be replaced with 4).*

---

The above is a Falkner-Skan equation. I want to get the numerical solution from 0 to 4.

Actually, I have read the book *Numerical Methods in Engineering with Python 3*, and used the methods in the book, but I cannot get the answer. Perhaps there are some errors in the book.

Here is my code:

```
"""
solve the differential equation
y''' + yy" + (1 - y'^2)= 0  y(0) = 0 y'(0) = 0,y'(+inf) = 0
"""
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from printSoln import *
start = time.clock()
def F(x,y):   # First-order differential equations
    y = np.zeros(3)
    F0 = y[0]
    F1 = y[2]
    F2 = y[2]
    F3 = -y[0]*y[2] - (1 - y[1]*y[1])
    return [F1,F2,F3]

def init(u):
    return np.array([0,0,u])
X = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
u = 0
for i in range(1):
    u += 1
    Y = odeint(F, init(u), X)
    print(Y)
    if abs(Y[len(Y)-1,1] - 1) < 0.001:
        print(i,'times iterations')
        printSoln(X,Y,freq=2)
        print("y'(inf)) = ", Y[len(Y)-1,1])
        print('y"(0) =',u)
        break
end = time.clock()

print('duration =',end - start)
```

Comment: Could you show your code, your trials and specify the problems you meet with

Comment: the printSoln is a formatted print funciton.I konw  my code is wrong ,I'm a freshman of Python

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with this code? Have you tried it step by step to see where it starts to deviate from your expected results?

Comment: "maybe there are some errors in the book" - it's far more likely that a "freshman of Python" has made the mistakes than the authors of the book.

Comment: 1. It is necessary to initialize X at every loop step, since X is changed after call odeint. 2. You need to decrease the step of u increment (for example u += 0.01). 3. You need to iterate much more times than 1 (for example for i in range(50). 4. Try to use less value of the tollerance (it is 0.001 now, for u +=0.01 I've used tol=0.1 (if you need higher tollerance you have to set smaller increment of u). After such improvments this code works.

Comment: And, of course it should be F1 = y[1] instead of F1 = y[2]

Comment: thanks your suggestitons ,but the anwser  I get is 0,can you rewrite the loop code?

Comment: tol = 0.1
for i in range(50):
    u += 0.01
    X = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
    Y = odeint(F, init(u), X)
    print Y[-1,:]
    if abs(Y[len(Y)-1,1] - 1) < tol:
        print(i,'times iterations')
        #printSoln(X,Y,freq=2)
        print("y'(inf)) = ", Y[len(Y)-1,1])
        print('y"(0) =',u)
        break

Comment: You have an f' in your equation.  Is that a first derivative for f(x)?  If yes, where are its equation and initial condition?  You need to solve four simultaneous first order ODEs

Comment: sorry, it should be y'.

Comment: Forget one more fing. Replace F(t,x) on F(x,t)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. Actually I don't know how to solve Two-Point Boundary Value Problems with the  module of scipy.integrate odeint.For example  the equation y" + 3yy' = 0  y(0) = 0 y(2) = 1.Can you show me the code for solving  this equaiton,print the anwser from 0 to 2 .

Comment: Shooting method. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method

Comment: @Roman Fursenko Thanks you very much.I know my fault

Answer (score 2):

The code you show is supposed to realize the shooting method to solve boundary value problem by reducing it to the initial value problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method).
However, there are many errors in the code.

1. By reading documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) for `odeint` function which is a core of the solution, one can find that first argument of the `odeint` is a `func(y, t0, ...)`. Therefore, we have to replace the line `def F(x,y):` by `def F(y,x):`
2. Function `F(y, x)` should computes the derivative of y at x. Rewriting the original 3rd order non-linear ODE as a system of three 1st order ODEs one can find that: (a) line `y = np.zeros(3)` does not make sense, since it forces all derivatives to be zero; (b) it should be `F1 = y[1]` instead of `F1 = y[2]` and (c) line `F0 = y[0]` is not necessary and can be deleted.
3. We have already figured out that the code should realize shooting method. It means that at the left boundary we have to set conditions `y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0` which we have from the problem statement. However, to solve initial value problem we need one more condition for `y''(0)`. The idea is that we will solve our system of ODEs with different conditions of the form `y''(0) = u` until for some value of `u` the solution satisfies boundary condition `y'(4) = 1` at the right boundary with given tolerance. Hence, for experiment purposes, let's replace line `for i in range(1):` by `for i in range(5):` and print the value of `y'(4)` by `print Y[-1,1]`. The output will be:

   ```
   -1.26999326625 
   19.263464565
   73.5661968483
   175.047093183
   340.424666137
   ```

It can be seen that if increment of `u` = 1: (a) `y'(4)` monotonically increase and (b) at u = 1 `y'(4)=-1.26999326625`, at u = 2 `y'(4)=19.263464565`. Therefore, the solution which satisfies boundary condition `y'(4)=1` can be found with `1<u<2`. So, we have to decrease the increment of `u` in order to find the solution with higher tolerance.

Finaly, we can rewrite the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import time

start = time.clock()
def F(y, x):   # First-order differential equations
    F1 = y[1]
    F2 = y[2]
    F3 = -y[0]*y[2] - (1 - y[1]*y[1])
    return [F1,F2,F3]

def init(u):
    return np.array([0,0,u])

X = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
niter = 100
u = 0
tol = 0.1
ustep = 0.01

for i in range(niter):
    u += ustep
    Y = odeint(F, init(u), X)
    print Y[-1,1]
    if abs(Y[len(Y)-1,1] - 1) < tol:
        print(i,'times iterations')
        print("y'(inf)) = ", Y[len(Y)-1,1])
        print('y"(0) =',u)
        break

end = time.clock()
print('duration =',end - start)

plt.plot(X, Y[:,0], label='y')
plt.plot(X, Y[:,1], label='y\'')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Numerical investigations with `ustep=0.01` shows that two diferent solutions are possible. One at `0<u<1` and another at `1<u<2`. These solutions are shown below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Fursenko ,you perfectly solved it,the second solution is what I need.In fact ,I have a  more precise method to solved without using  odeint function.

Comment: @Smithermin, of course it can be solved by different ways. Here I have answered your question based on your original approach to the problem. You can upvote and accept the answer if it is satisfactory =)

Comment: Fursenko,yes,you do help me a lot .I have not  read the odeint function carefully.So I almost became mad for this .In fact ,the first method I used is this latest method shown by me,but I can't get the result,so I find another method to solve it ,then I found the  odeint function in scipy.But as the same I  didn't get the right anwser.And now ,I found my fault of the previous mehtod.The point is that the root  search funtion  have probelms.Anyway ,thanks you.My English is not well,so I don't know  whether or not I make you understand.

Comment: For that answer, Roman, you should have gotten ten upvotes. Too bad @Smithermin never accepted your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
# biscetion
""" root = bisection(f,x1,x2,switch=0,tol=1.0e-9).
Finds a root of f(x) = 0 by bisection.
The root must be bracketed in (x1,x2).
Setting switch = 1 returns root = None if
f(x) increases upon bisection.
"""
import math
from numpy import sign
def bisection(f,x1,x2,switch=1,tol=1.0e-9):
    f1 = f(x1)
    if f1 == 0.0: return x1
    f2 = f(x2)
    if f2 == 0.0: return x2
    if sign(f1) == sign(f2):
        print('Root is not bracketed')
    n = int(math.ceil(math.log(abs(x2 - x1)/tol)/math.log(2.0)))
    for i in range(n):
        x3 = 0.5*(x1 + x2); f3 = f(x3)
        if (switch == 1) and (abs(f3) > abs(f1)) \
            and (abs(f3) > abs(f2)):
            return None

        if f3 == 0.0: return x3
        if sign(f2)!= sign(f3): x1 = x3; f1 = f3
        else: x2 = x3; f2 = f3
    return (x1 + x2)/2.0
""""//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"""
# run_kut4
""" X,Y = integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h).
    4th-order Runge-Kutta method for solving the
    initail value problem {y}' = {F(x,{y})},where
    {y} = {y[0],y[1],...,y[n-1]}.
    x,y = initial conditions
    xStop = terminal value of x
    h     =increment of x used in integration
    F     =user - supplied function that returns the 
           array F(x,y) = {y'[0],y'[1],...,y'[n-1]}.
"""
import numpy as np
def integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h):

    def run_kut4(F,x,y,h):
        K0 = h*F(x,y)
        K1 = h*F(x + h/2.0, y + K0/2.0)
        K2 = h*F(x + h/2.0, y + K1/2.0)
        K3 = h*F(x + h, y + K2)
        return (K0 + 2.0*K1 + 2.0*K2 + K3)/6.0
    X = []
    Y = []
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
    while x < xStop:
        h = min(h,xStop - x)
        y = y + run_kut4(F,x,y,h)
        x = x + h
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)
""""//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"""    
## printsSoln
""" printSoln(X,Y,freq).
    Prints X and Y returner from the differential
    equation solves using printout frequency 'freq'.
        freq = n prints every nth step.
        freq = 0 prints inital and final values only.
"""
def printSoln(X,Y,freq):

    def printHead(n):
        print('\n{:>13}'.format('x'),end=" ")
        for i in range(n):
            print('{}{}{}{}'.format(' '*(9),'y[',i,']'),end=" ")
        print()
    def printLine(x,y,n):
        print("{:13.4}".format(x),end=" ")
        for i in range(n):
            print("{:13.4f}".format(y[i]),end=" ")
        print()
    m = len(Y)
    try: n  = len(Y[0])
    except TypeError: n = 1
    if freq == 0: freq = m
    printHead(n)
    for i in range(0,m,freq):
        printLine(X[i],Y[i],n)
    if i != m - 1: printLine(X[m - 1],Y[m - 1],n)
""""//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////""" 

"""
solve the differential equation
y''' + yy" + B(1 - y'^2)= 0  y(0) = 0 y'(0) = 0,y'(+inf) = 0
B = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,-0.1,-0.15]
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
start = time.clock()
def initCond(u): #Init. values of [y.y']; use 'u' if unkown 
    return np.array([0.0,0.0,u])

def r(u):   # Boundart condition resdiual
    X,Y = integrate(F,xStart,initCond(u),xStop,h)
    y = Y[len(Y) - 1]
    r = y[1] - 1.0
    return r

def F(x,y):   # Third-order differential equations
    F = np.zeros(3)
    F[0] = y[1]
    F[1] = y[2]
    F[2] = -y[0]*y[2] - (1 - y[1]*y[1])
    return F

xStart = 0.0   # Start of integration
xStop = 5    # End of integraiton
u1 = 1.0       # 1st trial value of unknown init. cond.
u2 = 2.0       # 2nd trial value of unknown init. cond.
h = 0.1        # Step size
freq = 2       # Printout frequency


u = bisection(r,u1,u2,tol = 1.0e-9) #Comput the correct initial condition
X,Y = integrate(F,xStart,initCond(u),xStop,h)
print(initCond(u))
printSoln(X,Y,freq)
end = time.clock()
print('duration =',end - start)
plt.plot(X, Y[:,0], label='y')
plt.plot(X, Y[:,1], label='y\'')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```